# the name of state when data reading from hard drive

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, operating-systems

In computer organization and architecture, what is the name of the state when data must be read from hard drive? I have tried to search it on StackOverflow and textbooks but could not find the answer.

Comment: I can't tell what state you're tring to describe. Could you give more detail?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about states of pages in a virtual memory system, there are several names that are used informally.  _Paged out_ (of main memory onto backing store) is one, _non-resident_ (in main memory) is another.  I'm sure there are others, computer architecture and operating systems are fields that aren't particularly rigorous in their terminology.

Comment: please add more details on your question. This can be "cache miss" if you have cache, "page fault" if virtual memory is used (as babou suggests), or even simply a  "Disk access", e.g., when you open a file and access it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "[page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)" ? That is when a virtual page has to be loaded from the disk, because it is not in RAM and has to beaccessed. Actually page fault is the name of an interrupt that is caused by that situation, and will lead to the loading of the needed page.